# Scrollable Column containing LayoutBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Here is my current layout

[image]

Along with the widget that builds it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
    List<Product> products,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Product> products;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TitleCard(),
          OptionsCard(),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) => GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: [
                  for (final product in products) ProductCard(product),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, only the grid of products in the layout builder is scrollable. When scrolling, I want the top two cards to scroll out of view first and then scroll through the list of products.

Is this possible with a nested LayoutBuilder? Trying to wrap the whole thing in a ListView failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your main `column` with `SingleChildScrollView`,then remove `Expanded` and add `shrinkWrap: true` and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to grid like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(// <-- add this
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TitleCard(),
          OptionsCard(),
          LayoutBuilder(// <-- remove expanded
            builder: (context, constraints) => GridView.count(
              shrinkWrap: true,// <-- add this
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),// <-- add this
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: [
                for (final product in products) ProductCard(product),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: @ColeVanVlack I updated my answer, check the last one

Comment: @ColeVanVlack did you problem solve?

Comment: your solution worked! I kept the LayoutBuilder because I am actually using the constraints to dictate the crossAxisCount. I had just removed that requirement to simplify the example. Thanks!